# Not so easy to solve Error: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment

Tags: java

Thank you for your help so far.

I thought this is an easy problem but I just cannot make my Windows know my JAVA_PATH.

[JAVA_HOME not found in your environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZy8P.jpg)

I've set my PATH: [PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yDlT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

On the windows command line, run `ECHO %JAVA_HOME%` and you'll likely find that it is *not* set.

That dialog box screenshot you pasted: Note that it doesn't instantly apply; you'd have to open up a new command line box; all existing ones don't pick up the setting. That is the most likely explanation for what you're witnessing here.

It's all a tad confusing; `JAVA_HOME` should not be necessary in the first place. Do you have a really old maven version perhaps?

Comment: Thank you, your feedback is so useful.